# If the number of edges on each face is three, then find the number of edges in $G$.

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Let $G$ be a connected planar graph with 20 vertices. If the number of edges on each face is three, then find the number of edges in $G$.

**My question is** what is meant by the terms "**If the number of edges on each face is three**" and what does it mean mathematically?

Can someone explain these terms for me so that I can complete the problem?

I am learning planar graphs right now in my class. I dont understand how to formulate the problem.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: something like this: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/96/Goldner-Harary_graph.svg see how each area is delimited by exactly 3 lines?

Comment: Do you know what a face is?  Think of a complete graph $K_4$ but draw it [like this](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:K4_planar.svg).  Here there are *four* faces (*don't forget to include the outside face*) and each face is enclosed by three edges.  Compare this to graphs like [these](https://media.springernature.com/lw685/springer-static/image/art%3A10.1007%2Fs00373-022-02480-4/MediaObjects/373_2022_2480_Fig1_HTML.png).  $A_2$ in the second image should be clear why it doesn't count, since there we see a face surrounded by four edges (*you see the square, right?*)...

Comment: @CarloMoretti; so how can we use it in our problem?

Comment: ...but actually all of them fail since remember that we count the outside as a face as well, making $A_1$'s outside face be enclosed by six edges, not three and so on...

Comment: @JMoravitz; I am comfortable with the idea of face, but i dont understand the terms i quoted

Comment: @JMoravitz; I understand why $K_4$ is planar, we have done it in class

Comment: My point is not to bring up the fact that $K_4$ is planar but is to give an example of a graph where every face had three edges on it, and in the later image to give examples of graphs who had faces which did *not* have three edges on them... since that is what you say you are having difficulty interpreting

Comment: @JMoravitz, my point is i understand what is meant by 3 edges on a face, but i dont understand how to use that in my problem

Comment: ... You should reread what you have written and understand why the way you have phrased your question sounds like you want the meaning of the phrase "*If the number of edges on each face is three*" explained.  So, you do not actually want that phrase explained but instead you want to know why that statement will imply something about the number of vertices?  Think about Euler's formula.  [See another larger graph](http://www.ams.org/featurecolumn/images/links41.gif) as a further hint about what your graph might look like.  Look up the word "triangulation."

Comment: @JMoravitz; I am still confused. Here we have $n-e+r=2, n=20.$ I need to find $e$, but I dont understand how can I find $r$ from the given information. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

We know that every edge is on the boundary of at most two faces.  We know that every face has at least three edges surrounding it.  This information tells us that $3|F|\leq 2|E|$.  According to the problem statement every face has exactly three edges on it.  This informs us that $3|F|=2|E|$.

We know that every connected simple planar graph satisfies Euler's formula: $|V|-|E|+|F|=2$, or rearranging that $|F|=2+|E|-|V|$

Combining these, we have $2|E|=^\dagger 3|F|=3(2+|E|-|V|)$ and by rearranging then we learn that $3|V|-6=|E|$.  (*In the case that we did not know every face has exactly three edges on it, we would have used an inequality at the equality marked with the $\dagger$, making the final generic result $3|V|-6\geq |E|$ with equality if and only if the graph is a [plane triangulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planar_graph#Maximal_planar_graphs)*)

We are told $|V|=20$.  That implies then that $|E|$ is equal to $60-6=54$

Comment: Thank you for the answer but I am still confused about how you got $3f=2e$

Comment: @Olivia do you remember how we proved the handshaking lemma?  How we had treated each edge as half of it pointing to the first endpoint and the other half to the other?  Same concept here.  Imagine an edge like a long hotdog bun comprised of what is effectively two pieces of bread, and we can unfold the hotdog bun... each half starting to cover some of the face associated with it... precisely a third of the space of the corresponding face.  Now, count the number of pieces of bread used in two ways: based on the number of edges... and based on the number of faces.

Comment: Each edge contributed two hotdogbun halves... one going towards one face and the other towards the other face.  So, the total number of pieces of bread used (*counting each hotdogbun half separately*) would be $2e$.  On the other hand, by counting using the faces, each face had three pieces of bread used to cover it... so there are $3f$ pieces of bread used in all.  Since the total amount of bread used is supposed to be the same regardless how we counted it, we learn then that $2e=3f$